# Why there is a behavior difference of SQL count(*) vs SQL count(numeric)

Tags: sql, sql-server, view, count, sql-view

I know that 
count(*) - will returns the total count of all rows including nulls.
count(colName) - will returns the total count of all rows in which colName is not null.

Today one of my college got an issue with count() in SQL. He was trying to get the count of rows from a view after applying some date filter.

**View Return Data structure**

```
 [Year]                 VARCHAR(4)        
,[Month]                VARCHAR(4)        
,AType                  VARCHAR(20)       
,PActualsID             INT               
,EID                    VARCHAR(12)       
,CID                    INT               
,CGId                   INT               
,EMargin                NUMERIC(17,3)     
,Period                 DATETIME          
,PLID                   INT               
,PCID                   INT               
,PSID                   INT               
,VPID                   INT               
,VSID                   INT               
,STID                   INT
```

**Query 1**

```
SELECT * from vw_ActualAllocation_New
where   EntityId = '442105'       and 
        Period   >= '01-Jan-2017' AND  Period  < '01-Jan-2018'
```

This returns around 94 records.

**Query 2**

```
SELECT Count(*) from vw_ActualAllocation_New
where   EID = '442105'    and 
        Period   >= '01-Jan-2017' AND  Period  < '01-Jan-2018'
```

This returns an error

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Conversion failed when converting
>   date and/or time from character string.

**Query 3**

```
SELECT Count(EMargin) from vw_ActualAllocation_New
where   EID = '442105'    and 
        Period   >= '01-Jan-2017' AND  Period  < '01-Jan-2018'
```

This returns me count as 94.

> Please note that EMargin is a NUMERIC datatype and all other types
>   such as int and varchar returns the same error.

Please share your thoughts on difference between these two behaviors.

***SQL Server Environment: Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (Hypervisor)***

**UPDATE - View Code**

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vw_ActualAllocation_New]
SELECT D.Year, D.Month, A.AType, A.PAID, D.EntityID, D.CustomerID
,B.CGId, SUM(A.EBITRMargin) AS EBITRMargin
,CONVERT(DATETIME,D.Month + '-01-' + D.Year) AS Period, D.PLID, D.PCID
,D.PSID, D.VPID, D.VSID,D.STID 
FROM  dbo.AAllocations AS A 
INNER JOIN dbo.PActuals AS D ON D.PActualsID = A.PActualsID AND D.Active = 1 
INNER JOIN dbo.Customer AS B ON D.CustomerID = B.CustomerID AND D.EntityID = 
B.EntityID 
INNER JOIN dbo.AStatus AS C ON  A.ASID = C.ASID
WHERE (A.Active = 1) AND (C.Active = 1) AND (C.Reference = 'Actuals') AND 
(C.Status = 1)
GROUP BY D.Year, D.Month, A.AType, A.PAID, D.EntityID, D.CustomerID, B.CGId, 
D.PLID, D.PCID, D.PSID, D.VPID, D.VSID, D.STID
```

**Update on Conclusion**

*Reached a conclusion as suggested by **Gordon**, and if you feels that you may have another thoughts, please post it here
Also I tried with the data from view, into a new table and its working fine. Issue happens while accessing directly from view. The view generation happens with lot of data and impossible to post it here because of its huge size and privacy agreements. Thanks for understanding my limitations and helping me*

Comment: What is the datatype of Period? You really should use ANSI compliant date strings.

Comment: the error has nothing to do with what you include in `count`. the date comparison fails as the error message suggests.

Comment: I kinda agree with vkp but it should not fail if it is the same query above an below. Puzzled honestly.

Comment: @SeanLange datatype for Period is SQL DateTime . In DB the value is something similar to `2017-01-01 00:00:00.000`

Comment: @vkp but the second query returns data. I was checking on any datatype or date comparison issue. accidentally I tried with the numeric col and then got the expected result.

Comment: Can you share some test data for us to repro the issue

Comment: @theGameiswar how can I share the test data

Comment: you can edit your question

Comment: The answer's always going to be the same. The two queries generate different execution plans (because one only needs to test for the existence of rows and one need to find non-null `EMargin` values). In turn, in one of the plans, a predicate is being pushed "deeper" than in the other, and so a comparison between a datetime and a string value is occurring *earlier* than some "guard" predicate that prevents inappropriate comparisons from occurring (when the string doesn't contain something date-like)

Comment: Show `vw_ActualAllocation_New` view please.

Comment: @TheGameiswar I was trying to get the data from a SQL view `(vw_ActualAllocation_New)`. I also tried to insert data into a table variable and executed the count(*) and it works fine.

Comment: To emphasize what Damien  is saying:  There is a bug in the view.  The fact that it works in one case just means that that case is hiding the bug.  The bug is related to type conversion (obviously) but it is hard to say the exact cause because you don't have the definition of the view in the question.

Comment: Reproducible example or it didn't happen.

Comment: Let me update the view. I need to edit the field names as I cant post the col names directly because some policy issues.

Comment: All updated the view code.

Comment: Any more details required other than data. Some one voted to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely cause of the problem is this line of code:

```
CONVERT(DATETIME, D.Month + '-01-' + D.Year) AS Period
```

In SQL Server, you should never use `CONVERT()` from a string to a date without specifying the format or using standard formats (YYYYMMDD is preferred by SQL Server but I consider YYYY-MM-DD to be acceptable as well).

In older versions of SQL Server, you can do:

```
CONVERT(DATE, d.Year + RIGHT('00' + D.Month, 2) + '01') as period
```

This conversion will always work.  In newer versions, use `datefromparts()`:

```
DATEFROMPARTS(d.Year, d.Month, 1) as Period
```

Why is this happening?  I speculate that the date format is being interpreted as DD-MM-YYYY instead of MM-DD-YYYY.  In other words, what you think is Feb 1st is really Jan 2nd.

Further, the period values for entity '442105' all convert to a reasonable dates.  The `WHERE` clause filters out the bad values.  The problem is with other entities and the issue, as Damien points out is where the values get evaluated in the execution engine.

Comment: I am getting values while select * from view, but getting the error while applying count(*)   `Cannot construct data type date, some of the arguments have values which are not valid.`

Comment: Earlier the period was datetime, now its was date.

Comment: I was trying like this `SELECT count(*) from vw_ActualAllocation_New_Edit
    WHERE   EntityId = '442105'       and 
            Period   >=  '2017-01-01'  AND  Period  <  '2018-01-01'`

Comment: I am also concluding with your approach